# Configure nginx : my browser always displays IP address instead of domain_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

With my web browser: when I go to my_domain.com => I am redirected to  XX.XX.XX.XX (the IP)
and the address displayed in my web browser remains XX.XX.XX.XX.

I want to point on XX.XX.XX.XX and I want the address displayed my_domain.com (same behaviour as in any website).

My configuration file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 24M;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/wrappers/ruby;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And this is my other configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my_domain.com;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

        location / {
                root /home/deploy/www/comint/current/public;
                passenger_enabled on;
                rails_env development;
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }
}
```

when I try to perform a redirect, I have a loop error.

I tried many configurations, but it seems that I misunderstood something.
May someone explain me what the problem can be ?

Thank you

PS: I'm a rails developper, but that's my first web server configuration.

Comment: Could you add all of your nginx configuration ?

Comment: I edited the question and nginx configuration added. Thanks.

Comment: Problem might be with your DNS, nginx looks good to me. Is `my_domain.com` an A (adress) entry?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is probably the problem (I cannot test right now as it take a few hours to take the A address into account). Thanks very much.